# Is the compiler allowed to not retract the stack pointer when an object on the stack goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, language-lawyer

I'm using a Raspberry Pi Pico, which has two cores, both with a 4KB stack, with core0's on top of core1's so that core0 gets to have 8KB of stack in single-threaded apps.

The gist of the issue sparking this question is as follows:

```
// Do stuff
{
    uint8_t buffer[4096];
    // Use buffer (for flash IO)
}
MyObject myObject = buildMyObject();
multicore_launch_core1(core1_entry); // Will allocate on its stack
// Use myObject
```

Here we allocate 4KB on the stack "while we have 8KB of stack". Then we make it go out of scope. Then we allocate another object on the stack. We then launch core1.

At this point, the bottom 4KB of the stack still belong to core0, the top 4KB now belong to core1. Core1 starts using them. We then use the previously allocated object.

I expect `myObject` to be in the first 4KB, because I expect `buffer` going out of its explicit scope to increase the stack pointer by 4KB immediately with regards to control flow.

This isn't what happens on GCC 10.3.1 arm-none-eabi. The 4KB of stack taken by `buffer` stay there, never to be given back until the enclosing scope (same as `myObject`'s) ends. Which of course, results in `myObject` being allocated in core1's stack-to-be. Chaos ensues.

This sounds counterintuitive to me and, in the context of embedded programming where we might not even have a heap, harmful.

Is this a compiler bug ? Or does the standard allow this to happen ?

Is the compiler allowed to not retract the stack pointer when an object on the stack gets out of scope ?

Comment: I don't think the language specification deals with this level of detail at all, so yes.

Comment: Yep. Typically you'll see the stack pointer move only twice, allocating the worst case scenario for the function and then returning to where it started when the function returns.

Comment: Just use the buffer in a function and return, then you'll definitely be ok

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of either doing that and annotate it to never inline, or just declare that my buffer ends at the top of the stack range...

Comment: @Brian I don't think so. I set CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT to -Wall in CMake, but I'm not too comfortable with CMake

Comment: The standard says nothing about "stack" (as an area of memory), stack pointers, or even about cores.   Which means an implementation (e.g. the designer of the compiler, informed by knowledge of capabilities of the host system) is free to manage such things as they see fit.   The standard talks about life times of objects, and when code can access them without causing undefined behaviour - not about how a compiler manages resources to achieve behaviours consistent with requirements of the standard.

Comment: I guess that makes sense... as-if rule. I'm surprised about it regardless, it sounds like this wasn't designed for constrained environments and I never thought I'd see the day where I found C++ not low-level enough. Thanks for your replies !

Comment: Isn't allocating 4K on the stack in an embedded small device application asking for trouble to start with? Wouldn't you be better off with a "scratch"' 4k global buffer instead?

Comment: For the vast majority of compilations, this optimization is unnecessary; and the extra instructions to adjust the stack pointer would actually make it a pessimization. So it's not too surprising that it isn't done by default.  Now, I could imagine that a compiler might provide an option to do it, especially a compiler designed mainly to target embedded systems (which gcc is not).  I did try `-fconserve-stack` but it doesn't do it.

Comment: If you're going to be programming for such tiny machines, then I think you will quickly encounter a lot more situations where C++ "isn't low level enough", nor even C.  Stack is a good example: modern compilers assume that nobody is messing with it behind their back, and perform aggressive optimizations accordingly.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, at first glance you'd think that, but if you point your stack at the free space and use the tools to partition that memory and handle its lifetimes via normal local variable and scoping rules, then it is significantly easier than doing it manually.   You do need to ensure your use of the stack doesn't exceed that memory, but that's what static analysis tools are for.   The OPs useage seems a bit prone to failure, though.

Comment: @RussSchultz  It's the (usually random) failure part that is worrisome.  The Pi Pico has only 4KB of stack per core, but another 256KB of SRAM, which is plenty. Julien:  Another solution would also be to move the code allocating 4KB on the stack into its own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is tagged `language-lawyer`: Neither C nor C++ standard make any guarantees over layout and location of memory. They don't have any real concept of a stack either. (In C++ there is a concept of "stack unwinding" which however doesn't really require a stack as in the memory concept and in C++23 there is support for stacktraces, but it also has no concept of memory addresses.)

There is also no standard-approved way of actually depending on the memory location chosen for variables. It is fundamentally impossible to get from a pointer to one of them to a pointer to another (without taking the address of the latter with `&` first and storing the result somewhere in an object reachable from the former). The compiler can assume that individual variables are completely independent in terms of their memory location and that they cannot be messed with from anything external. It can (and does) for example reorder the location of variables on the stack in whatever way deemed suitable for optimization. It may also add padding, etc. It may decide arbitrarily to reuse storage of variables whose storage duration has ended, but it doesn't have to either.

Everything you are doing that allows you to do context switches or the like is completely outside the standard's specification and dependent on the C++ implementation, i.e. compiler, architecture, etc.

For your use case it seems that you likely want to write inline assembly (also a compiler-specific extension) so that you have control over where your data is located in memory. Alternatively there may be other compiler-specific extensions such as attributes to help with that.